# Adding MouseClick event on System.Windows.Input.Mouse

Tags: c#, .net

(I am newbie and this is probably a duplicate question.)

To see which control is clicked on form, I have a method like this;

```
    public void  IdentifyControl(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Control ctrl = sender as Control;
        if (ctrl != null)
            SelectedControl = ctrl;

        this.Cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Handle);

        MessageBox.Show(""+ctrl.GetChildAtPoint(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position).ToString());

    }
```

and trying to call it from mouse click. 
In my first attempt, I added this function to main forms MouseClick event but it only worked for form itself but controls in form. Then I tried to create a general click event and use by Mouse class.

The main point I stuck is that I couldn't create the suitable parameters Mouse.AddMouseUpHandler(DependencyObject element,
    MouseButtonEventHandler handler)
Its probably because of I don't know event handling but maybe I am all in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mouse click event just double clicking on any buttons, labels, etc, and the Visual studio will create a code for you, like this:

```
private void YOUROBJECT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Just put the method you want into this click event.
Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks, I know creating this kind of events but; I dont want to create the same mouse event for all components of the form. This is not a useful way, I think

Comment: Just for understanding, you want your method to be called on the clicking of ALL component of your form?